# Opening VSD files with Visio 2010 Viewer

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-visio, viewer, microsoft-visio-2010

I just installed the [Visio 2010 viewer](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=21701).

How do I now make this viewer to open if I double click a VSD files? Every time I do so only my web browser (Opera) is started - but it is not associated with the VSD file extension.

I tried to manually assign VSD files to the viewer but I wasn't able to find the viewer executable file.

Comment: Despite the name, Visio 2010 viewer, is not a stand-alone application, but it is a plug-in to Internet Explorer. As such it does not really work well. For instance, for printing properly, there is often no other way than to zoom, take a screenshot, crop (in, say, Paint) and print out through some other program, say Word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

The problem is that the registry entries are incorrectly set by the Visio Viewer installer.

You have to **delete** the registry key

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisioViewer.Viewer\shell\open\ddeexec
```

Then you have to **add  `"%1"`** to the value of

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisioViewer.Viewer\shell\open\command
```

so that it looks as follows:

```
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" -nohome "%1"
```

Answer (score 2):

The site to which you linked says the viewer only works in Internet Explorer 5 through 8.

> Visio Viewer is implemented as an ActiveX control that loads and
>   renders Visio drawings inside Internet Explorer.
>
> This download works with the following program: Microsoft Internet
>   Explorer 5, 6, 7, or 8.

Comment: If I associate VSD files with IE then Opera comes up as it is my default web browser. Stupid IE. If I start iexplore.exe from command line with the VSD as parameter it works!?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the "Microsfot Visio Document" add-on is not disabled in Internet Explorer.
You can see the installed add-ons in Internet Explorer, under:

Tools button (upper right hand corner) > Internet Options > Programs tab > "manage add-ons" button

Comment: there is no add-on even if it was installed :(